# How To Upload A File On A Client Machine To My Server With JS, HTML, ETC?

Tags: html, file-upload, client

Is it possible for a webpage on a remote client to upload a file from that remote client to my server without serverside ASP, PHP, etc? My server is an embedded webserver that can serve up html pages and service cgi commands but little else. I want it to serve a page to the client that allows the client browser to select a local file and upload it to my embedded server.

The http fileupload object is a perfect start for allowing the remote user to select the file they want to upload. But once they've selected the file how do I open it and send it to my embedded server? This is to be used to allow a remote user to upload a firmware update (binary file ~600k ish) to my embedded hardware using their web browser.

Thanks in advance for any help

~Tim

Comment: If you can't use any server-side code to handle the upload, this does not seem possible.

Comment: I can write standard C/C++ code on the serverside to send data (strings and such) to the client but the RTOS being used doesn't have support for running any scripting type code (ASP, PHP, etc). Any way to do this using cgi function calls? Thanks!

Comment: How about this. Is there any way for a webpage to read a file on a client computer using nothing but HTML and JS? If I can read the file I can transfer the file contents to my server manually.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Server side is absolutely necessary to do any kind of uploading.

Sorry charlie